# How to search JSON data in mysql using Regular expression in Strongloop

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have stored JSON data in table. I want to fetch data based on userId, userId is a property of Users Object.

> Example: I want fetch all the records if users contain 513

My table data sample:

```
Table name:share

Id  name            sharedusers
1   xxxx            {"accessType":0,"permission":"1","specificUsers":
                    [{"users":"502,512,513","permission":"1"}]}

2   yyy             {"accessType":0,"permission":"1","specificUsers":
                    [{"users":"47,52,60","permission":"1"}]} 

3   zzzz            {"accessType":0,"permission":"1","specificUsers":
                    [{"users":"502,512,513","permission":"1"}]}
```

> I tried following query in find() method but is not working, its
>   showing error..

```
{"where": {"sharedusers": {"regexp": "/"users":"[^"]*\b513\b/"}}}

{"where": {"sharedusers": {"regexp": /"users":"[^"]*\b513\b/
}}}
{"where": {"sharedusers": /"users":"[^"]*\b513\b/} }

{"where": {"sharedusers": "/"users":"[^"]*\b513\b/"} }

and also i tried restcall

filter[where][share][regexp]=/"users":"[^"]*\b513\b/
```

> In MySql I have tried following code its working fine But I dont know
>   how to do same thing in strongloop.

```
SELECT * FROM share where sharedusers REGEXP '"users":"[^"]*[[:<:]]513[[:>:]]';
```

My model definition:

```
{
  "name": "share",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "sharedusers": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Mysql version : '5.6.27-log'

Comment: You should know that this query is not likely to be fast. It will almost certainly require a table scan and hence be linear in the number of rows in your table.

Comment: @ChrisKitching I accept your comment but we have only limit of records.

Answer (score 0):

Strongloop does some work for you in subfields when datatype if object, this leads to some counter-intuitive queries like in your situation (but very intuitive when you are used to MongoDB/Postgres query style)

You should use

```
{"where": {"sharedusers.users": {"regexp": "[^\"]*[[:<:]]513[[:>:]]" }}}
```

From what I understand of your query, the regexp is not matching:

```
{"where": {"sharedusers.users": "/(513,|,513,|513$)/" }}
```

You could change your database storage to have `users` as an array of strings: if you are using MySQL with JSON support (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) it would be a lot faster and you could do the following:

```
{"where": {"sharedusers.users": "513" }}
```

It would be a lot faster

Edit: after multiple comments and question update, my answer is not valid because you are using a String datatype for the sharedusers field.

Comment: I tried this one {"where": {"sharedusers.users": {"regexp": "[^\"]*[[:<:]]513[[:>:]]" }}}    but I am getting  empty array.

Comment: This is because your regex does not match, try ```/(513,|,513,|513$)/```

Comment: I have tried memory storage and mysql. mysql return error"unknown column".  memory storage return empty array. can you provide sample app?

Comment: Can you add your model definition in the question, and the MySQL version used? So I can try with the same datatype on my side

Comment: While trying I see that on the first field you have ```" users"``` instead of ```"users"```, could it be it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105431/discussion-between-jonathan-muller-and-riaz-as-kather).

Comment: {"where": {"sharedusers": {"regexp": "/513/" } } } I am tried this code Its return all values if any thing match in object {"accessType":0,"permission":"1","specificUsers":
                    [{" users":"502,512,513","permission":"1"}]} . for example  {"where": {"sharedusers": {"regexp": "/0/" } } } I tried this query it return result because of accessType":0. I want find in specificuser area.

Comment: You are embedding sub objects into strings stored in a database that does not support JSON: you should consider update your DB and change your model, or use proper relations in your strongloop definitions

Comment: I have changed string into array. that is {"accessType":0,"permission":"1","specificUsers":
                    [{"users":["502","512","513"],"permission":"1"}]} it is correct ?

Comment: Yes. And once the datatype is object you can use ```"sharedusers.users": "513" ```

Comment: I am tried but I getting error unknown column. and I have checked table schema in mysql, it showing datatype is TEXT. my model definition I have mention object.

Comment: I think this is because your are not using mysql 5.7. Does in memory works?

Comment: yes I tried it return empty array. can you provide any sample?